# How to hide a element using plain JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to hide a `p` tag using plain `JavaScript`. I don't want to use React. I am new to HTML and Javascript. Please excuse if this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Set the `display` style to `none`. Or give it a class whose `CSS` has `display: none;` style.

Comment: hide it when a button is clicked, when x equals 2, when? have you tried anything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can hide elements using css. See below:-

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("p-tag").style.display = "none"
}, 1000)
```

```html
<p id="p-tag">Hello</p>
```

Comment: It works. Very helpful for creating a interactive code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the p element by setting its display property to none or visibility property to hidden. If you want to completely hide it you can do the following.

```
document.querySelector('p').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your html tag in javascript, you can do that by setting a class or an id to your p tag and then set it to display: none;

For example :

```html
<p id="text">My text to hide</p>
```

```js
let myTextToHide = document.getElementById("text").style.display = 'none';
```